# Can I have a summarize of what Ruby module do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do know it is a namespace thing ... can anyone give me some sample code ... i understand things fast with sample code ... thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A module in ruby can be used for 3 possible things

### 1. Namespacing

This is pretty straight forward.

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end

f = Foo::Bar.new
```

### 2. Collection of functions

Sometimes, you will have some functions that don't really fit in any class. In something like java, you would just put them as a bunch of static methods on a class. In ruby, you would put them on a module, since having them on a class implies the class is intended to be instanciated

```
module FooHelper
  def self.bar
    puts 'hi'
  end
end
FooHelper.bar # => hi
```

### 3. Mixins

This is the hardest to understand of all 3. Basically, it is rubys answer to multiple inheritance in C, or interfaces in java.

Sometimes you have logic which belongs in several classes, but at the same time doesn't fit as a parent class. A mixin describes "mixing" a modules methods into a class. There is actually a lot more to this, but at an extremely high level, it would look like this

```
module CanFoo
  def foo
    puts 'bar'
  end
end

class Baz
  include CanFoo
end

class Bar
  include CanFoo
end

baz.new.foo # => bar
bar.new.foo # => bar
```

mixins are a fairly advanced topic, and it takes a bit of time to understand when you would use one over a super class. IMO they are one of the coolest features of ruby though, and handles the multiple inheritance problem with a great deal more elegance then any other OO language I have looked at.

Comment: what if
    module A 
    module B
    class C
    def foo
    end
    end
    end
    end
A::foo or B::foo?

Comment: C#foo actually (# is how you indicate an instance method) modules only get mixed in if you include them. In the case where you include multiple modules with the same method in the same class, the last one you include will be the one it uses (although you can still use the super keyword to get at the ones that happened further up the inheritance chain)

Answer (score 1):

A module is a collection of constants, class and functions inside a namespace. Here is an example:

```
module Payments
  CARD_TYPES = ["visa", "mastercard"]

  class CreditCard
    attr_accessor :number
    attr_accessor :type
  end

  extend self
  def process_payment
   ...
  end
end
```

I now have a Payments module. I can call Payments::CARD_TYPES to get an array; Payments::CreditCard.new to create an object and Payments::process_payment to call a function.